# Проблема с прогресс баром в JQuery

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

В документации JQuery есть пункт про progressbar, но при использовании выдаёт ошибку. Что делать?
Код:
`$( ".progress-bar" ).progressbar({value: 25});`
Ошибка:
`$(...).progressbar is not a function`

Comment: _Что делать?_ - подключить jquery ui